# Swift Map styling with GMS

Tags: ios, swift, styles, gmsmapview

Im using `GMS` (Google Maps SDK) In my current project, and it looks like this
[image]

Is it possible to `style` the map to something like this? and still use `GMS`.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can customize the map the way you want here: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Once you are done with customization, copy the json and add it your project in a file say **style.json**

Then assign this styling to your map as:

```
do {
            // Set the map style by passing the URL of the local file.
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
                mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)

            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use [custom tiles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles):

```
class TestTileLayer: GMSSyncTileLayer {
 override func tileForX(x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> UIImage? {
    // On every odd tile, render an image.
    let image = "\(x)-\(y)-\(zoom)"
    return UIImage(named: image)
  }
}
```

the tiles can come from a server with an http request or from your bundle.
Basically a tile is an image which show a piece of map at `x` - `z` with a `zoom`.

usage:

```
let layer = TestTileLayer()
layer.map = mapView
```